# how to change visited link color dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created dynamic list(list with hyperlink) using jquery.when I click that link fo rthe first time it will go to the next page.
I used the cookie for save the index of link value while I am clicking that link.Again run that application 
get the saved index value from cookie in onload.Using that value change the color that particular link.
Now I want to I will run that application again that link is displayed in red color  and the other links(unvisited) are displayed in blue color.
 How to do this?

```
   $(".sidemenu li ").click(function() {  
              var index = $('li').index(this); 
             // alert(index);
              checkCookie(index);
            // saveid(index);
              });

    }   

    function checkCookie(index)
    {

     var linkindexvalue=index;
     // alert(linkindexvalue);
      setCookie("indexvalue",linkindexvalue,365);


    }

    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + value;
    alert(document.cookie);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var list=getCookie("indexvalue");
    if(list=='1'){
    alert(" ");

     $(".sidemenu li").css("background-color","red");

    }

  });

    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    alert("hj");
    var value = "";
    var DocumentCookie = " " + document.cookie + ";";
    var CookieSearchStr = " " + c_name + "=";
    var CookieStartPosition = DocumentCookie.indexOf(CookieSearchStr);
    var CookieEndPosition;

    if (CookieStartPosition != -1) {
    CookieStartPosition += CookieSearchStr.length;
    CookieEndPosition = DocumentCookie.indexOf(";", CookieStartPosition);
    value = unescape(DocumentCookie.substring(CookieStartPosition, CookieEndPosition));
    }

    return value;

    }
```

please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually the [jQuery Visited plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/) that let you get the visited links in your page.

Once included, you can select the links and attach a class with the new colour:

```
$('.sidemenu li a').visited().addClass('visited');
```

Notice that in this case you have to add an `<a>` inside your `<li>`s, since I don't think the visited feature it's strictly related to links on a anchor, not clicks on a list item.

If on the contrary you need to go for the cookies options, give me some time to check your code! :)

Comment: Hai davide, Thanks for your reply.I already used that plugin.But color is not changed .So that only I will use cookie.Please tell me how to use that plugin/cookies.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use css :visited tag. Else if you want to do so by jquery without any plugin then see my implementation on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JjMAX/1/.

Comment: Hai sarthak gupta,I create a dynamic list(add <a> inside the<li> ).In your code use pointer value and that value is declared in div.In that place how I will use index value of paricular link(I am getting index value using $('li').index(this);).please guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two aspects: 1. set the cookie for the index clicked on and retrieve it on subsequent pageloads. 2. Set the css property for visited links. I assume you have the first thing working correctly. (Is It?) . For the seond part I'll need the exact markup for the exact jquery code.

Comment: Ok,sarthak gupta.how I will find index value (each hyperlink) of dynamic list in onload.If I find that index value in onload function.I will add css for that particular index(index value of link).Please help me how to find that value and add css.Thanks in advance.

Comment: where to see that updated fiddle? please give link to that updated fiddle.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you Sarthak Gupta.Thank you very much for your reply.I got it.It's worked fine.